# Charset MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, encoding

Hello I have a website (Italian) where many people could register. Sometimes people are chinese or russian so they input in chinese or cyrillic keyboard language.
What happens on my DB (MS Sql Server 2014 SQL Server 12.0.2000) is that the fields are filled by "?" and the user when come back after registration see "???" as their name.
Fields in DB are varchar (but I tried also nvarchar). The collate of DB is Latin1_General_CI_AS.
What I need to do to allow this? and if there's a solution, what happens for old records in DB? 
Thank you

Comment: You need to use nvarchar, which allows for Unicode.

Comment: Column datatype should be `nvarchar` and while inserting try to set charset to `utf8`.

Comment: You ask what happens to old records:  If the data has been stored in a varchar, then it is lost.  If you see a '?', then that is what is stored in that field.  Using nvarchar will only help for new data.

Comment: I already tried with nVarchar but nothing changes to me. Maybe because I need to set charset to utf8 while inserting? but how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Person(PersonName varchar(30))

insert into Person ( PersonName ) values
( 'Валерий' ),
( '미정' )

select * from Person

-- Result is:
-- PersonName
-- ------------------------------
-- ???????             -- These question marks have           
-- ???                 -- been saved in your table.

alter table Person alter column PersonName nvarchar(30)

insert into Person ( PersonName ) values
( N'Валерий' ),       -- Note use of N prefix
( N'미정' )          -- which indicates an nvarchar string

select * from Person

--Result is:
-- ------------------------------
-- ???????            -- Sorry, old data is lost
-- ???
-- Валерий
-- 미정
```